# How do I create a remote Git branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I created a local branch. How do I push it to the remote server?

**UPDATE: I have written a [simpler answer for Git 2.0 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27185855/109305).**

Comment: did anyone ever answer you second question?  >>And how would I tell my colleagues to pull it from the upstream repository?

Comment: Possibly related: [Pro Git: 3.5 Git Branching - Remote Branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

Comment: @milkplus `get fetch --all` fetches the new branches on the remote side (but only a `get fetch --prune` deletes locally the references to the deleted remote branches). I think, either this should be set up by them automatically, or you have to talk to them verbally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

Comment: _There is a similar question here on Stack Overflow on how to track a newly created remote branch._ - You haven't told us what question you have in mind. My guess would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650. In line with the comment by @Trevor Boyd Smith I consider both your question here _and_ [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650) duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/.

Comment: works for me! March 2024

Answer (score 421, accepted):

### Simple Git 2.0+ solution:

As of **Git 2.0, the behavior has become simpler**:

You can configure git with **`push.default = current`** to make life easier:

I added this so now I can just push a new branch upstream with

```
$ git push -u
```

`-u` will track remote branch of the same name. Now with this configuration, you will auto-guess the remote reference to git push. From [git.config documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> **push.default**
>
> Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is explicitly given.
>
> **`push.default = current`** - push the current branch to update a branch with the
> same name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.

For me, this is a good simplification of my day-to-day Git workflow. The configuration setting takes care of the 'usual' use case where you add a branch locally and want to create it remotely. Also, I can just as easily create local branches from remotes by just doing `git co remote_branch_name` (as opposed to using `--set-upstream-to` flag).

I know this question and the accepted answers are rather old, but the behavior has changed so that now configuration options exist to make your workflow simpler.

To add to your global Git configuration, run this on the command line:

```
$ git config --global push.default current
```

Comment: I find `git push -u origin HEAD` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21991290/2448440) a bit more verbose (you write what you are doing) without being too much to type.

Furthermore, a `git push -u` without additional arguments did not work for me if the branch was created with `-t`

Comment: `git config --global push.default upstream && git checkout -b foo && <change a file> && git push -u` does not work (as of git 2.19.1); push requires the remote and branch arguments.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by `git co remote_branch_name`?

Comment: Didn't work for me. Solved by adding to `~/.profile`: `function gitb() { git checkout -b $1 && git push --set-upstream origin $1; }` and then can do `gitb feature/abcd` - this sets it up for `git pull` and `git push` without extra arguments + pushes the new branch into the remote repo to verify that the name is really free.

Comment: @youurayy you probably forgot also to add `-u` flag to `git push -u`  and also check your `git config --list` that it contains `push.default=current`

For me, `git push -u` just works. Also be aware that as of Git v2.27, you are prompted to set a default push strategy. So maybe your defaults are not different?

Comment: @JesperRønn-Jensen see that is exactly the point -- one simple alias-like bash function, and you don't have to remember nor do any of those.

Comment: Depressingly, `git` has changed behavior and this no longer works.

Answer (score 4245):

First, create a new local branch and check it out:

```
git checkout -b <branch-name>
```

The remote branch is automatically created when you push it to the remote server:

```
git push <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

`<remote-name>` is typically `origin`, which is the name which git gives to the remote you cloned from. Your colleagues may then simply pull that branch.

Note however that formally, the format is:

```
git push <remote-name> <local-branch-name>:<remote-branch-name>
```

But when you omit one, it assumes both branch names are the same. Having said this, as a word of **caution**, do not make the critical mistake of specifying only `:<remote-branch-name>` (with the colon), or the remote branch will be deleted!

---

So that a subsequent `git pull` will know what to do, you might instead want to use:

```
git push --set-upstream <remote-name> <local-branch-name>
```

As described below, the `--set-upstream` option sets up an upstream branch:

> For every branch that is up to date or
> successfully pushed, add upstream
> (tracking) reference, used by
> argument-less git-pull(1) and other
> commands.

Comment: Note that default behavior of git is to push ***matching*** refs, so `git push <remote>` would not push branch if it is not present on `<remote>`.

Comment: You might want to use `git push -u <remote-name> <branch-name>`
instead, so that a subsequent `git pull` will know what to do.

Comment: Instead of explicitly specifying the server name, you can just use `origin`, which means "the server I got the rest of this repo from": thus `git push origin <branch-name>`.

Comment: @Bart-Schuller, the `-u` is very important! I keep coming back to this question/answer to remember it.

Comment: in my case `git push <remote-name> <local-branch-name>:<remote-branch-name>` works, but `git push <remote-name> <branch-name>` get error "error: src refspec current does not match any."

Comment: If it's a new branch on the remote it seems it's not enough, I got: `error: unable to push to unqualified destination: branch-name
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.` I had to prefix the remote branch name with `refs/` to make it work. Thus `git push <remote-name> <local-branch-name>:<refs/remote-branch-name>`.

Comment: If you forget to use the `-u` option, you can just type `git push -u` afterwards in the branch, then `git pull` will work.

Comment: @Jan If you don't specify a branch name, this will setup remote tracking on *all* of your branches. Not normally a bad thing, but something to be aware of.

Comment: Putting it all together, `git push -u origin <local-branch-name>` is what worked for me.

Comment: @AndresRiofrio That would create a new branch based on the current branch.

Comment: @Snicolas What you described is possible, but not necessary. You can leave out the remote-branch-name and git will use the same name as the local branch.

Comment: This solution doesn't works for me (maybe because I'm using the new default of `push.default`, which is `simple`). It works only if the local branch creation uses -t: `git checkout -t -b your_branch`. I'm wondering how to push a branch created without the `-t`, though.

Comment: Arh! Where <remote-name> could be "origin"... Damn that took me a while to figure out [still noob]

Comment: when to do git add and git commit ? before creating local branch or after that?

Comment: @user1735921 Add and commit should happen after you created the branch, otherwise that commit would be created on the current branch.

Comment: Is `your_branch` and `branch-name` the same? Is my remote name origin or master? I'm a little confused here

Comment: @HrvojeT I made the branch-name more consistent. The remote name is explained in the post, but master is (almost) never the name of a remote (unless someone gets it into their mind to call their remote master).

Comment: So, __origin__ is a remote repository, and __master__ and __branch-name__ are branches in that remote repository, usually

Comment: @jww If you read correctly, you see it says: git push **<remote>** <branch>. You failed to specify a remote, and just repeated the branch name twice.

Comment: Is there any way that I can create a remote branch from another remote branch without fetching it locally?

Comment: What `-b` does in `git checkout -b <branch-name>` ?

Comment: @Shafizadeh It tells git checkout you want to create a new branch (instead of checking out an existing one or checking out a file).

Comment: For those a little confused about the `-u`, [here's a better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma).

Answer (score 1019):

First, you must create your branch locally

```bash
git checkout -b your_branch
```

After that, you can work locally in your branch, when you are ready to share the branch, push it. The next command push the branch to the remote repository origin and tracks it

```bash
git push -u origin your_branch
```

Teammates can reach your branch, by doing:

```bash
git fetch
git checkout origin/your_branch
```

You can continue working in the branch and pushing whenever you want without passing arguments to git push (argumentless git push will push the master to remote master, your_branch local to remote your_branch, etc...)

```bash
git push
```

Teammates can push to your branch by doing commits and then push explicitly

```bash
# ... work ...
git commit
# ... work ...
git commit
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/your_branch
```

Or tracking the branch to avoid the arguments to git push

```bash
git checkout --track -b your_branch origin/your_branch
# ... work ...
git commit
# ... work ...
git commit
git push
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a remote branch without creating a local branch of the same name?

Comment: @ArielGabizon Not 100% sure what you mean since you usually start your work locally (i.e. local branch named first) or pull an existing remote branch. But you can specify a new name when you initially push it to remote: `git push -u origin [local-branch-name]:[remote-branch-name]`. You can also specify your own branch name when you pull a remote branch: `git branch -t -b [local-branch-name] origin/[remote-branch-name]`.

Comment: @dseminara what's the utility of  `-u` ?

Comment: @Gass -u is a shortcut for --set-upstream , it updates your local branch registry to track the new created branch, it's , you need to use that option (either -u or --set-upstream, both are the same) if you want your future invokations of push where they have to send the information to, without having to be explicit about the involved branches everytime

Comment: @ArielGabizon yes, it can be done like that, I do prefer to make explicit "refs/heads/[remote-branch-name]" after the ":"

I like to have same name local branches to avoid confusions, but that use of the command push is very handy to manipulate remotes, including tags

Answer (score 95):

As stated in the previous answers,

```
git push <remote-name> <local-branch-name>:<remote-branch-name>
```

is enough for pushing a local branch.

Your colleagues, can pull all remote branches (including new ones) with this command:

```
git remote update
```

Then, to make changes on the branch, the usual flow:

```
git checkout -b <local-branch-name> <remote-name>/<remote-branch-name>
```

Comment: I like this cause it allows the remote name to be different than the local one

Comment: great, I can bar baz now.

Answer (score 94):

Create a new branch locally based on the current branch:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

Commit any changes as you normally would.  Then, push it upstream:

```
git push -u origin HEAD
```

This is a shortcut to push the current branch to a branch of the same name on `origin` and track it so that you don't need to specify `origin HEAD` in the future.

Comment: This helped in my case: `git push -u origin HEAD`.
I think it's the most clear way.

Comment: Yeah, you never remember what you last typed as a branch, exactly, so this is the way to go.

Comment: @marksyzm If you can't remember what branch you're on or what you named it, you probably shouldn't be pushing at all!  At least, not without running `git status` first.

Comment: Yeah, gotta make sure the world doesn't explode on that push; I agree.

Comment: This is the most efficient way to create a tracking branch as well as a remote branch at the same time.  I'd also like to add `git remote show origin` as a third step just to visualize the new tracking/tracked relationship.

Answer (score 84):

If you want to create a branch from the current branch

```
git checkout -b {your_local_branch_name}
```

you want a branch from a remote branch, you can try

```
git checkout -b {your_local_branch_name} origin/<remote_branch_name>
```

If you are done with changes you can add the file.

```
git add -A or git add <each_file_names>
```

Then do a commit locally

```
git commit -m 'your commit message'
```

When you want to push to remote repo

```
git push -u origin <your_local_branch_name>
```

All together will be

```
git checkout -b bug_fixes
```

or
If you want to create a local branch `bug_fixes` from a remote branch, say `development`

```
git checkout -b bug_fixes origin/development
```

You can push to the branch to remote repo by

```
git push -u origin bug_fixes
```

Anytime you want to update your branch from any other branch say `master`,

```
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 70):

## [Quick Answer]

You can do it in 2 steps:

**1.** Use the `checkout` for create the local branch:

```
git checkout -b yourBranchName
```

**2.** Use the `push` command to autocreate the branch and send the code to the remote repository:

```
git push -u origin yourBranchName
```

> There are multiple ways to do this but I think that this way is really simple.

Answer (score 52):

If you wanna actually just create remote branch without having the local one, you can do it like this:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/foo
```

It pushes whatever is your HEAD to branch *foo* that did not exist on the remote.

Comment: Doing this completely confused my Visual Studio to the point where it wouldn't start up correctly. The Team Explorer wouldn't load at all, but everything else went bonkers throwing errors also. Just FYI.

Comment: This sounds like it should work, but when I actually tried it, the our gitlab server didn't recognise the result as a branch.

Comment: What branch is foo branched off of on the remote? What if I wanted to foo to branch off of foo2? Is that possible? Thank you.

Comment: It works on gerrit server as well, creating a new branch on the remote that didn't exist before this command.

Answer (score 35):

Easiest Solution... Drumm Roll... **git version 2.10.1 (Apple Git-78)**

```
1) git checkout -b localBranchNameThatDoesNotExistInRemote

2) Do your changes, and do a git commit 

3) git push origin localBranchNameThatDoesNotExistInRemote --force
```

N.B. - The branch you just created in your local environment, and the remote non-existing branch where you are trying to push, **must have the same name**.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Even though you call this an easy solution, I still think `git push -u` is way easier. Requires that you have one global config line, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27185855/109305.

I use `git push -u` constantly, it covers 99% of my usecases when working.

Answer (score 30):

First you create the branch locally:

```
git checkout -b your_branch
```

And then to create the branch remotely:

```
git push --set-upstream origin your_branch
```

Note: This works on the latests versions of git:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.3.0
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is just the help text generated by the command `git push` when your local branch is not tracked by a remote.

Answer (score 22):

you can simply,

1. `git checkout -b YOUR-NEW-BRANCH-NAME`
2. `git add .`
3. `git push origin YOUR-NEW-BRANCH-NAME`

you can see your branch with the code under the relevant git repo

Cheers !! :)

Answer (score 20):

> Create the branch on your local machine and switch in this branch :

```
$ git checkout -b [name_of_your_new_branch]
```

Push the branch on github :

```
$ git push origin [name_of_your_new_branch]
```

When you want to commit something in your branch, be sure to be in your branch.

You can see all branches created by using :

```
$ git branch
```

Which will show :

```
* approval_messages
  master
  master_clean
```

Add a new remote for your branch :

```
$ git remote add [name_of_your_remote]
```

Push changes from your commit into your branch :

```
$ git push origin [name_of_your_remote]
```

Update your branch when the original branch from official repository has been updated :

```
$ git fetch [name_of_your_remote]
```

Then you need to apply to merge changes, if your branch is derivated from develop you need to do :

```
$ git merge [name_of_your_remote]/develop
```

Delete a branch on your local filesystem :

```
$ git branch -d [name_of_your_new_branch]
```

To force the deletion of local branch on your filesystem :

```
$ git branch -D [name_of_your_new_branch]
```

Delete the branch on github :

```
$ git push origin :[name_of_your_new_branch]
```

[Here All Information](https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches)

[Other Existing project](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)

Answer (score 14):

Creating a local branch from an existing branch (can be master/ develop/ any-other-branch).

> git checkout -b branch_name

Push this to remote

> git push -u remote_name local_branch_name:remote_branch_name

Here,

1. -u : sets the upstream branch
2. remote_name : git sets the name by default to be "origin" when it creates the repository. This can however be changed to a different arbitrary name.
3. local_branch_name : is the name of the local branch to be pushed.
4. remote_branch_name : is the name of the remote branch that we want to be created on remote.

If we remove the local and remote branch names, it will have the format

> git push -u remote_name branch_name

This will push the local branch to remote and with the same name as the local branch branch_name. The local branch will be tracking the remote branch as well.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is well answered, but just wanted to list the steps I take to create a new branch "myNewBranch" and push to remote ("origin" in my case) and set up tracking. Consider this the "TL;DR" version :)

```
# create new branch and checkout that branch
git checkout -b myNewBranch
# now push branch to remote 
git push origin myNewBranch
# set up the new branch to track remote branch from origin
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/myNewBranch myNewBranch
```

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to add that while:

```
git checkout -b {branchName}
```

Creates a new branch, it also checks out that branch / makes it your current branch. If, for some reason, all you want to do is snap off a branch but not make it your current branch, then you would use the following command:

```
git branch {branchName}
```

In the first command, "checkout" makes said branch your current branch, and the "-b" means: this branch doesn't exist yet, so make it for me.

Answer (score 7):

Now with git, you can just type, when you are in the correct branch

`git push --set-upstream origin <remote-branch-name`>

and git create for you the origin branch.

Comment: -u is short for --set-upstream..  so command could be git push -u origin <remote-branch-name>

Comment: fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

Comment: maybe you have to set the origin of your git repository

Answer (score 7):

How to do through Source Tree

```
 1: Open SourceTree, click on Repository -> Checkout
 2: Click on Create New Branch
 3: Select the branch where you want to get code for new branch 
 4: Give your branch name
 5: Push the branch  (by click on Push-button)
```

Answer (score 4):

`git push -u <remote-name> <branch-name>` doesn't work if the newly created branch isn't spawned from the same repo, i.e. if you haven't created the new branch using `git checkout -b new_branch`, then this will not work.

For eg, I had cloned two different repositories locally and I had to copy repo2/branch1 to  repo1/ and then push it too.

[This](http://cmdlinelinux.blogspot.com/2014/02/git-push-new-local-branch-cloned-from.html) link helped me push my local branch (cloned from another repo) to my remote repo:

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Git 2.37.0, you do not need "--set-upstream origin" anymore. Just `git push`. You can achieve this with the `push.autoSetupRemote` option enabled

`git config --global --add --bool push.autoSetupRemote true`

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you do it in eclipse through Egit.

1. Go the "Git Repository Exploring" view and expand the git project to which you want to create a branch. Under Branches -> Local .. select the branch for which you want to create the branch ( In my case I selected master .. you can select another branch if you wish) .. then right click and click on Create Branch option .. and select the checkout this project option and then click the finish button.
2. Now from the project explorer select the project .. right click then Team -> Push Branch.

A new remote branch will be created. You can give the name of the branch to your colleagues so that they can pull it.

Comment: Tangential warning about Egit -- and all JGit-based clients, AFAIK: they don't support .gitattributes! This means if your team uses a mix of Windows(CRLF) and Linux/OSX(LF) you must depend on each client having the right settings at all times. Naturally it's better to manage line endings centrally at the repo or project level, and .gitattributes is the supported way to do this. So, if you don't absolutely have to use Egit... don't! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used two ways to create branch

If you are using TortoiseGit follow these steps:-

1.Create Branch using TortoiseGit

> > Right click on your project >>> TortoiseGit >>> Create Branch >>> write the name of branch and select the base branch then press ok

2.Push the branch

> > Right click on your project >>> TortoiseGit >>> push >>> click ok

3.Switch to new branch

> > Right click on your project >>> TortoiseGit >>> Switch/Checkout >>> select newly created branch and press ok

If you are using command prompt follow these steps:-

1.Create branch using command prompt

> > $git checkout -b new_branch_name

2.Push the branch

> > $git push origin new_branch_name

3.Switch to new branch 
it will already switched to new_branch_name otherwise you can use

> > $git checkout new_branch_name

Answer (score 1):

To create a new branch in remote, you can use the following command:

`git checkout -b <new-branch-name>`

For example, to create a new branch called "feature_branch", you would use the following command:

`git checkout -b feature_branch`

This will create a new branch locally, but it will not push it to the remote repository. To push the new branch to the remote repository, you can use the following command:

`git push origin feature_branch`

For example, to push the "feature_branch" branch to the remote repository, you would use the following command:

`git push origin feature_branch`

This will push the new branch to the remote repository, and it will be available to other users.

Here are some additional things to keep in mind about creating new branches in remote:

You can use the git branch -l command to list all of the branches in your local repository.

You can use the git checkout  command to switch to a different branch.

You can use the git merge  command to merge a branch into the current branch.

You can use the git reset --hard  command to reset the current branch to the state of the specified branch.

Answer (score -1):

I use this and it is pretty handy:

```
git config --global alias.mkdir '!git checkout -b $1; git status; git push -u origin $1; exit;'
```

> Usage: git mkdir NEW_BRANCH

You don't even need git status; maybe, I just want to make sure everything is going well...

You can have BOTH the LOCAL and REMOTE branch with a single command.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this by adding this into my bash `~/.profile`:

`function gitb() { git checkout -b $1 && git push --set-upstream origin $1; }`

Then to start up a new local + remote branch, I write:

`gitb feature/mynewbranch`

This creates the branch *and* does the first push, not just to setup tracking (so that later `git pull` and `git push` work without extra arguments), but actually confirming that the target repo doesn't already have such branch in it.

Answer (score -1):

Heres an example I only have two branches that were local first: origin and mobile-test.

Nothing for me worked until I used this in command line to actually show my updated files in a remote branch.

```
git push --set-upstream origin mobile-test
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have used `--single-branch` to clone the current branch, use this to create a new branch from the current:

```
git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
git push -u origin <new-branch-name>
git remote set-branches origin --add <new-branch-name>
git fetch
```