# upstream in git and use of -u flags in push

Tags: git

what is use of -u flag while pushing commits to some git repo? I mean what is differnece between `git push origin master` and `git push -u origin master` ? Can anyone please describe its usage ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly does the "u" do? "git push -u origin master" vs "git push origin master"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma)

Comment: @KyleTrauberman it is indeed. Would you mind voting to close it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does the "u" do? "git push -u origin master" vs "git push origin master"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma)

Answer (score 36):

The git(1) manual page says:

```
-u, --set-upstream
```

> For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add
>   upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1)
>   and other commands. For more information, see branch..merge
>   in git-config(1).

Basically, you use this flag when you want to set *origin* as the upstream remote for a branch. This is needed if you don't want to manually specify the remote every time you use `git pull`.

#### See Also

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches

Comment: Thanks for explaining the documentation. Gotta love git's docs for its clearness (sarcasm).