# Pushing a branch to a remote repository in git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, ruby-on-rails-3.2, git-fork

I'm trying to update the 3-2-stable branch on my fork of the Ruby on Rails project. So after cloning rails, I initially did a `git checkout -b my_branch remotes/origin/3-2-stable`. Then I made my changes. Then I added my fork as a remote repository with `git remote add my_fork git@github.com:myusername/rails.git`. Does a `git push my_fork my_branch` update the 3-2-stable branch only in `my_fork`? Is there something special I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does a `git push my_fork my_branch` update the `3-2-stable` branch only in my_fork?

Yes it will. It won't affect any other repo.
Note that the `3-2-stable` on your fork won't be impacted either: a *new* branch `my_branch` will be created on your fork to reflect your local branch.

But if you want to push/pull that branch from the repo `my_fork`, then this would make it easier:

```
 git push -u my_fork my_branch
```

See "[What exactly does the “u” do? “git push -u origin master” vs “git push origin master”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma)" for more on setting the upstream branch of a local branch.