# Git remote branch tracking - am I doing it right?

Tags: git

I have just read this question/answer:

[what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma)

However I am still a little unclear on a couple of points:

1. If I forget to do `git push -u origin myBranch`, and instead I simply do `git push origin myBranch`, can I correct it by then doing a `git push -u origin` myBranch?

It seemed to work, because when I do a `git branch -vv` I can see that both the origin/master and myBranch are tracked.

But is that correct? - should they both be tracked or have I got it wrong by doing this?

2. Is doing `git push -u <remote> HEAD` really equivalent to `git push -u origin myBranch`?
3. Finally I would like to put down an example of what I did just to make sure there are no issues with the way I am working.

Here is my little scenario...

```
# Recursive clone to to get the submodules
git clone <URL> -b topLevel --recursive
# Create my branch
git branch myBranch
# Now switch to my branch
git checkout myBranch
# Now add my branch to the remote
git push origin myBranch
# ...make some local changes...
git commit -am "did some changes"
# Oops I forgot to do the tracking... but I want to push my changes up...
git push -u origin myBranch
# Finally go into development loop:

# ... Do some changes...
git commit -am "did some changes"
git push
# repeat
```

Comment: When you do `git push origin myBranch` Git will by default set your local `myBranch` to use `origin/myBranch` to track the remote.  So I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just trying to use parameter-less "git push" and "git pull". I am trying to get my head around weather I am doing things right or not. There seem to be lots of answers out there that suggest that your your first action on creating a branch should be `git push -u origin myBranch` to setup the upstream tracking... your comment suggests that you don't need to do this at all? - you can simply use `git push` and `git pull` straight away?

Comment: Also - someone is very harsh to -1 this question. I have done my research and come up short. I have an example. I have a (couple of ) clear question... don't really see the problem.... feed back would be useful

Comment: Yes, you don't need to do this, unless you want to point to a different remote tracking branch.  This is an atypical use case in my experience.  I have upvoted you to counter.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ah thanks for that confirmation (and the up-vote counter). If you want to stick that in as an answer I will mark it up : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is nothing to correct. You've done nothing wrong. Adding the `-u` just adds an upstream tracking reference so that in the future you can use an argumentless `git pull` without needing to specify the remote and branch. If you forget the `-u`, just use it next time. (You can also set up tracking manually if you'd prefer.)
2. If your remote and `origin` are the same thing (which is likely if you cloned your repo from the remote in question), and if `HEAD` and `myBranch` are the same thing (which is likely if you're currently working on `myBranch`), then yes, those are equivalent.
3. There is no problem in your example scenario.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers. I guess HEAD refers to a particular "commit-hash" (one of those long IDs, probably got the terminology wrong here). Just one question then - Tim comments that you don't need to do any of this to use parameter-less `git pull/push`. I am not trying to cross-check his comment - I am sure its correct because I was just testing it.... but there are lots of answers out there suggesting that I need to do the `git push -u origin myBranch` first... so probably I just don't need to do any of this :o

Comment: Tim is right, you only really need to do this if you are trying to point a local branch to a remote branch with a different name, i.e. `git push -u origin master:other` with push local `master` to remote `other`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... that whole tracking branch with a different name sounds confusing!

Comment: It is, but there are uses for it. I've only ever had to do that once or twice, and I guess I'd assumed you were doing something like that here! Since you aren't, you are definitely overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for total clarity (if that's possible with Git :-) ), there are a couple of mostly-independent pieces here.

Every (local) branch can have one *upstream*.  The upstream setting has several older names, but let's stick with "upstream" because it's the *best* name.  :-) This upstream is what determines the parameter-free `git push` and `git merge` and `git rebase`.  (I recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely at this point—all it does is run `git fetch` and then either `git merge` or `git rebase`, and it's better to manually control whether you do a merge or a rebase, until you're really familiar with Git so that you can recognize which one it did when things go wrong, as they always do eventually.  Usually rebase is better anyway, and `pull` defaults to merging.  You can reconfigure `pull`'s default, but unless you're as obsessed with keystroke counting as the Git folks seem to be, I say: don't bother.)

There are many ways to *set* the upstream.  (Note, by the way, that there's only one upstream—or, if you *un*-set it, *no* upstream.  The point here, though, is that there are never two or more upstreams.)  Once set, it gives you a bunch of conveniences.  Besides the parameter-free commands, `git status` tells you more stuff, for instance.

The most direct way to set it is `git branch --set-upstream-to`.<sup>1</sup>  You can set the current branch's upstream:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/zorg
```

or set some *other* branch's upstream:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/zorg my-other-branch
```

(I'm using different local and remote-tracking branch names in this example, which is generally a bit unwise, but then again, why do you want to set your upstream to evilness? :-) ).

The thing is, the argument to `--set-upstream-to`—the *remote-tracking branch* name—has to be the name of an actual, existing remote-tracking branch that *is there* in your own repository right now.  (Remember, a remote-tracking branch name is something in *your* repository.  It's just called "remote-tracking" because your Git automatically updates it to what your Git sees on *their* Git, when you `git fetch` from the remote.)

When you create a *new* branch—one that *doesn't exist on the remote* yet—your own Git doesn't have a remote-tracking branch yet either.  How could it?  Your remote-tracking branches come from the remote, and they don't have it yet!  So this means you *can't* use `git branch --set-upstream-to`, at least, not yet.

Once you *do* `git push` this new branch, your remote will have the branch, and your Git will add the corresponding remote-tracking branch.  Then you'll be able to use `git branch --set-upstream-to`.  But, [*quelle horreur*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quelle_horreur), that requires typing in *two commands!*  Hence, `git push` grew a `--set-upstream` aka `-u` option, so that you can tell your Git: "do this push, and then do the `--set-upstream-to` thing too."  Because we all know that using two commands, like `git fetchentergit rebase`, is far too much to type when we could type `git pull --rebase` instead.  Why, that saves three whole keystrokes!

(Slightly more seriously, the `-u` option to `git push` also works around complaints that can happen depending on how you have `push.default` configured.  So it not only reduces keystrokes, it *sometimes* reduces confusion.)

Unless you need to *change* the upstream setting for some reason, you need only set it once.  You can do that any time after the first push with `git branch`, or during the first push with `-u`, or any time after the first push with another push with `-u`.  This just *re-sets* it.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is also `git branch --set-upstream`.  One might think, given the Git programmers' obsession with fewer keystrokes, that this would be the command to use.  But it has the wrong argument order: it got this shorter name by virtue of being put into `git branch` first.  Then they found that people kept getting the arguments wrong, so they added the longer command-option.

Comment: Nice explanation... and entertaining along with it (+1 just for that : ) ... to be honest, I am probably one of those keyboard-illiterate software engineers with a phobia of pressing too many keys, so I am fully up for `git pull--rebase`  option :o