# How to push a tag to a remote repository

Tags: git-tag

Hey please someone help me,
I am new to git.
I pull the code from repo,
and modified locally  and I want to push my changes to remote repo tag
but when i tried to push 
:git push origin tagname 
I am getting message like "Everything up-to-date"
Please some one help me.
And i got one more doubt what is the difference between 
:git push origin tagname  and :git push upstream tagname

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly does the "u" do? "git push -u origin master" vs "git push origin master"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma)

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to push single tag

```
$git push  <REMOTE_NAME> <TAG_NAME>
```

Eg:`$git push origin MyTag`

Use best practices like below to avoid branch name and tag name collision

```
$git push origin refs/tags/MyTag
```

Use below command to push all your tags

```
$git push  <REMOTE_NAME> --tags
```

Comment: HI Gurucharan, Thanks for replay. I tried :git push origin tagname, And I got below message "Everything up-to-date". my local changes doesn't reflected at repo tag. Thanks