# How many times do I need to use the -u option for git push?

Tags: git, git-push

I'm not sure if I just need to use this once or every time.

Can I do a

> git push -u repo branch

and from there just do a

> git push repo branch

because it has already been set?  Or do I need the -u every time?
g
**Research**

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push/1.6.1.3

[What exactly does the "u" do? "git push -u origin master" vs "git push origin master"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma)

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* to use it at all. You can push branches just fine without it. But if you want to set up the tracking, then just once is enough (when you first push a new branch).

Or you can add tracking later:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> <local_branch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain it  :)

---

- `-u` just a shorthand of `--set-upstream`

It means for every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, 
add upstream (tracking) reference so that you can just type the command `git push your-branch-name` to push without specifying the remote. Otherwise, it doesn't know where you want to push.

`git push -u` is same as `git push --set-upstream`

---

Once you set up the upstream, the "upstream" configuration will be saved to git-config and you no need to tell Git anymore about the upstream of this branch.
So you just need to execute it once.

After that, you may just simply push the branch using `git push your-branch` or `git push` for the current branch.

Hope this can help!