# How to change the URL on a local repository from GitLab to GitHub?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-remote, git-fetch

I had a repository on GitLab which I also published on GitHub.

As of now all the Git commands I am using are making changes on GitLab. However, I want those commits on GitHub.

I tried the command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:repo-url
```

Can someone suggest me how to set the URL so that commands would work on GitHub and not GitLab?

Comment: `git remote set-url origin <new-url>` is right command to change remote address.
If you prefer using ssh then set new-url to `git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` format. For https it would look like this `https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2432764/11725753)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**If you want to use both GitHub and GitLab:**

```
git remote add github <your-github-url>  # create a remote for GitHub
git remote add gitlab <your-gitlab-url>  # create another remote for GitLab
git push -u github <local_branch_name>   # set the default upstream to GitHub
```

**If you want to change your remote URL from GitLab to GitHub**:

```
git remote set-url origin <your-github-url>  # use GitHub as your (only) origin
```

See also ["How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository) and ["What exactly does the “u” do? “git push -u origin master” vs “git push origin master”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma)".

Answer (score 2):

Check what the repository is linked to with the command:
`git remote -v`

If it is linked to multiple url's that may be the issue. Try to remove the unwanted url with the command:
`git remote rm <destination>`

Then check again which repos are linked, by running `git remote -v` once more.