# Pushing git branch to the remote with new branch name

Tags: git

I have a local branch which is a new branch called `A`.

I want to push it to the remote, but I want it to be named differently in the remote.

For example, remote name would be `users/me/A` but in local, it would still be called `A`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:
`git push remoteRepo localBranchName:desiredName`

Here is some [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch/1519032#1519032) on the process

Answer (score 3):

You can push a local branch `A` to a remote branch `B` using this command:

```
git push -u origin A:refs/heads/B
```

`-u` flag will let you not specify the name of the remote branch in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch --set-upstream a origin/me/a
```

will set it permanently, so you don't have to specify the remote with every pull.  Add

```
[push] default=tracking
```

to your .git/config so that pushes go the same places pulls come from.