# git branching experimental

Tags: c++, git, branch

Well I've been working for a project. today I was experimenting with windows specific `wchar` and I needed to do change a lot of code since morning and I ended up with an ugly mess. That I can clear out latter but right now I need to do some mainstream works on last working commit. But I don't want to loose this work. So how can I keep this work in some branch for future and revert my workspace back to last commit ?

Comment: Did you commit any of your change already ?

Comment: No still waiting and thinking what todo

Comment: I think `stash` could work here.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Neel wants his work in a separate branch, `stash` only saves the changes on the "stash stack."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new branch and commit your changes to it:

```
git checkout -b topic/ugly-mess
git commit -a -m 'Checkpointing mess.'
```

Then go back to your mainstream branch which has the last working commit:

```
git checkout master
```

If you want your to publish your "local mess" upstream, push the branch:

```
git push origin topic/ugly-mess
```

Comment: don't I need to push after commit and before checkout master ?

Comment: You only need to push if you want your "local mess" to be available upstream. (I modified the answer accordingly.)

Comment: Yes I want that mess to be available upstream for future such that I can play with it latter. do I need to push it after checking out master ? and do I need to explicitly specify the name of branch ?

Comment: Regardless of the push, the branch will be available in the future. You can always check it out via `git checkout topic/ugly-mess`. Pushing it upstream *(i)* makes a it available to other users, and *(ii)* backs it up in case your local disk fails. And yes, you need to specify the branch if you are currently in master and want to push another branch. You could [setup tracking](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1519006/1170277), though, to avoid specifying the branch name when pushing.

Comment: But If I don't push It will be available **locally** only ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new branch

```
git branch -b wchar_migration
```

and commit your changes into it

```
git commit -am "wchar ..."
```

then go back to your work

```
git checkout master
```

If later you want to include the modification you made on master, simply rebase on it.

```
git co wchar_migration
git rebase master
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't even need a branch. If you use `git stash`, git stashes (stores) the current 'dirty' workspace and returns you to a clean workspace. You can `apply` the stashed changes later if you want.

Comment: Yes, you can. Stashes are local, though, and are supposed to be short-lived, so I don't see why you would want to. Take a look at the git-stash manual page for all the options.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you haven't committed any of this work, you can always [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) your experiment.

But you've described this as *experimental* so another option, and probably the better one, is to keep this work in it's own branch, e.g. `git checkout -b wcharExperiment`, commit the work into this new branch, then checkout your main branch.