# How to push a locally-create branch

Tags: git

I created a new local branch using the Git GUI. I committed to it. I want to push it so its backed-up.

I just did a `git push` thinking it'd know what to do. Thinking it would push my branch up and make one on the server.

This Q/A seems to say it should:

[How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch)

However, I get this error.

> ! [remote rejected] MyBranchName -> MyBranchName (no such ref)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'http_link_not_allowed_by_SO'

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the remote repository has been configured not to allow you to push new branches.

Comment: I've no idea what that means. I created it. Obviously there's no 'server' Git product. I use an ASP.NET demo call GitAspx, I think.

Comment: http://nhumanities.blogspot.com/2008/10/it-aint-what-you-dont-know-that-hurts.html

Comment: Run the command `git branch -a` and tell us the result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the remote repo got corruptified. That's a word. On the server, in refs/heads/ was a folder for the branch, which made it appear that it had gotten so far to pushing and died.

So I renamed it and pushed again and it was fine.

**Update**

It actually seems that the problem recurs again. It's like I can only push a branch once.