# How do I configure a remote repository to accept locally-created branches?

Tags: git

This question:

[How to push a locally-create branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692239/git-how-to-push-a-locally-create-branch)

Received a +1 comment:

> It looks like the remote repository has been configured not to allow
>   you to push new branches.

Now, I created the remote repository using this ASP.NET project:

http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/06/25/hosting-a-git-server-under-iis7-on-windows/

So, how do configure the remote repository to accept new branches? For the record, I can't imagine Jeremy's code does anything to disable pushing branches.

The remote repo has otherwise been working perfectly until I tried to push a branch created locally.

**Update 1**

- The remote repo has bare = true in the config file.
- There is also a folder with my branch name in it in the server refs\heads folder so it must have pushed something.

Luke

Comment: what error do you receive? Is your remote repository a bare repo? (You can find this by running `git config core.bare`). Notice that you are not allowed to push into a non bare repository.

Comment: The repo has only logs, objects, refs, config and HEAD folders. It doesn't look like a normal repo. Running `git status` says `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

Comment: @niculare Okay, I have bare = true in the config on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the remote repo got corruptified. That's a word. On the server, in refs/heads/ was a folder for the branch, which made it appear that it had gotten so far to pushing and died.

So I renamed it and pushed again and it was fine.

**Update**

It actually seems that the problem recurs again. It's like I can only push a branch once.

Comment: Hold your horses, I'm not allowed to yet!

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this (for reference, not an answer!) is that the remote repository is handled by e.g. [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), which does allow fine-grained control over what remote users are allowed to do. Plain git repositories can't be configured to disallow accesses AFAIK. Either you have full read/write access, or none. The only way to restrict writing is to use file/directory permissions.