# Best way to send a git repo with uncomitted changes?

Tags: git

I have a git repo with lots of uncommitted changes. What's the best way to send my uncommitted changes for someone else to continue work on?

Comment: You need to make a branch -- this is the standard workflow for git.

Comment: If you don't want to affect your master branch, create a new branch and push it up to your repo if you want to experiment. There's no reason not to 'commit' the changes, because you won't be able to share them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a feature branch:

```
git checkout -b MySpecialFeature
```

Commit to the feature branch:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "All my changes for SpecialFeature."
```

Push that branch remotely.

```
git push -u origin MySpecialFeature
```

Then have your special someone checkout your feature branch.

```
git checkout origin/MySpecialFeature
```

For a detailed discussion of git remote branches, see:
[How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch)