# How to push to a remote branch without providing the full push refspec?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have two branches on my remote: master and "cms". Now when I push to the cms branch I have to type: `git push origin HEAD:cms`. Is that really how it works or is there a shortcut command that I can use?

Basically I'd like to have to option to choose to switch between each of my remote branches in the same way that I do it with my local branches. How do I do that?

Comment: Setting the upstream branch as suggested is a good way to shortcut push specifications. The answer to this **[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch/)** might also be useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do:

`git branch -u origin/cms`

and if the local branch cms is not the current branch

`git branch -u origin/cms cms`

these commands will set you up so you can do:

`git push origin cms`

=]

Answer (score 0):

If the `cms` branch exists in remote, and if you are currently working in that branch, simply 
`git push` is enough.

It should work for you.