# git- Creating a branch which will be pushed to a remote later

Tags: git

I have a script which automatically creates a new branch with a name based on external information (JIRA ticket). I don't want to create the remote branch until I've committed and pushed some code, but I don't want to have to do "git push --set-upstream origin"

In other words, I want to set the upstream before I push.

```
git checkout -b mybranch
git <do-something-to-prepare origin/mybranch without talking to origin>
<do work>
git commit -a -m "Made my changes."
git push
```

I've tried:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/mynewbranch
```

This results in:

```
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/mynewbranch' does not exist.
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch/1519032#1519032

Comment: @DKrueger That creates a remote branch before its ready. I'm doing these commands in a script, and I don't want the script creating a remote branch, just preparing it so that I can create the remote by simply typing "git push".

Comment: @Daniel So you want to have `origin/myBranch` without `origin` actually having `myBranch`?

Comment: @Schleis Yes, that is the heart of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using the following commands:

```
git config branch.mybranch.remote origin
git config branch.mybranch.merge refs/heads/mybranch
```

This essentially configures the same thing as `--set-upstream-to` without checking that the upstream branch already exists first.

The next step is to change the `push.default` option, which currently (Git 1.9) defaults to `matching` (the documentation says this default will change to `simple` in Git 2.0). Using `matching` won't do what you want because there is no matching branch at the upstream remote yet. So:

```
git config push.default simple
```

You can set this globally (for all your repositories) using the `--global` switch.

After doing this, a

```
git push
```

will push the current branch (and only the current branch) to its upstream (which you set above), creating the upstream branch if necessary.

Comment: This works exactly as I had wanted! Thanks.  I thought I had tried this too, but must have missed some critical part.  My push.default was already set to simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-u` option when you push to track your local branch

```
git push -u origin myBranch
```

http://csurs.csr.uky.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+git-push

Comment: This causes the remote to have the branch before its ready (see other answer). Not quite what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try `--track` instead of `--set-upstream-to`, eg:

`git branch --track origin/mynewbranch`

I haven't found out exactly what the difference between the two is, but `--track` seems to do what you're wanting (and what I was wanting to do when I found this question!)