# how to address Git error "the requested upstream branch 'upstream/master' does not exist"

Tags: git

I am attempting to follow some steps to contribute to a repository on GitHub and one of the steps is not working. The steps are here: https://github.com/wdbm/qTox/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#how-to-open-a-pull-request.

I fork the repository on GitHub.

I clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/<YOUR_USER>/qTox.git
```

I access the directory of the local repository:

```
cd qTox
```

I add the upstream remote in order to be able to fetch from the upstream repository:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/qTox/qTox.git
```

I attempt to point the local master branch to the upstream repository:

```
git branch master --set-upstream-to=upstream/master
```

This command fails with the following error message:

```
error: the requested upstream branch 'upstream/master' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

How should I address this error? I am using Git 2.9.3.

Comment: did you run "git fetch", as the hint says? also, what branch are you in locally?

Comment: @zim Thanks for your suggestion. I tried running `git fetch`, but I still get the same error when I run `git branch master --set-upstream-to=upstream/master`. I am attempting to following the steps described [here](https://github.com/wdbm/qTox/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#how-to-open-a-pull-request).

Comment: can you show the output from these two commands: "git status" and "git remote -v"?

Comment: @zim `git status` shows "On branch master Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'." and `git remote -v` shows origin (both fetch and push) as `https://github.com/<MY_USER>/qTox.git` and upstream (both fetch and push) as `https://github.com/qTox/qTox.git`.

Comment: good, that looks rights. check out the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080952/git-creating-a-branch-which-will-be-pushed-to-a-remote-later

Comment: @zim Sorry, I'm lost. When I try the next step in the documentation (`git fetch upstream master:master`) I get the error message "fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository" which does not sound right.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`git fetch upstream master:master`: this work [only when you are not on `master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32561463/6309).
If you are on `master`, a simple `git fetch upstream` is enough.

Then you can link your local `master` to the remote tracking branch `upstream/master` (which has just been fetched)

```
git branch -u upstream/master master
```

Then you can use `git pull` to update `master`.
Again, if you are not on `master`, then yes, `git fetch upstream master:master` will work.

---

[Luh_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206998/juh) mentions also a typo issue in the refspec: see "[git fetch doesn't fetch all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58588706/6309)".

Comment: `git fetch upstream` was what did it for me on my `master` branch! I kept doing `git fetch`, like the hint said, but that did nothing. git's hints could really be a bit more specific(=practical) sometimes. Thank you!

Comment: @MaximizedAction True, the remote name is important in this case. Without it, Git would use by default the name "`origin`".

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem, however `git fetch` didn't solve my problem. Also, in my case I found that `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` didn't return anything [while it is suppose to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941875/1206998)

My problem was that there was a typo in the `.git/config` file in the fetch line of the respective remote block (probably something I added by mistake previously). So, check if your remote entry in the `.git/config file` is correct, e.g.:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://[server]/[user or organization]/[repo].git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You can also directly [remove and re-add the remote entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49185949/1206998)

Comment: Thanks, after hours trying to fix this error, I dicover that the old developer had left this config wrong

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in latest version of git the help text is out-dated.

I was running into this:

```
$ git pull origin master
From github.com:TextUsBiz/tesseract
 * branch                master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
fatal: the requested upstream branch 'origin/master' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.setUpstreamFailure false"
```

I thought the error message was quite odd, but.. I tried this, and it worked!

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=master master
branch 'master' set up to track 'origin/master'.
```

Comment: @VonC Do you know how to maybe file a bug with git core or submit a PR yourself?

Answer (score -6):

Try this

```
git branch -u git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<remote branch> branch
```

Comment: I see this everywhere... what do you put for <remote> no help really.