# How to create topic branch with a correspondingly configured remote tracking branch in one command

Tags: git

With one git command and a string argument `<topic-name>` how can I,

1. Create a local branch named `topic/<topic-name>`
2. Checkout this branch
3. Ensure the first `git push` with no args pushes to `origin/topic/<topic-name>` without warnings or prompts
4. Ensure that subsequent `git push` commands with no args push to `origin/topic/<topic-name>` without warnings or prompts

Assume `origin/topic/<topic-name>` does not exist on as a branch on the remote repo.

I'm open to the use of git aliases to achieve this.

Comment: Do you find `git checkout -b topic/<topic-name> origin/topic/<topic-name>` too long?!

Comment: Yes, far too long! The repetition of the topic name is the pitfall here.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work,

```
git config --global alias.topic '!f() { b="topic/$1"; git checkout -b "$b"; git config branch."$b".remote origin; git config branch."$b".merge refs/heads/"$b"; }; f'
```

### Output

```
$ git topic SI-9008
Switched to a new branch 'topic/SI-9008'
$ git push
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: Create pull request for topic/SI-9008:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx/pull-requests/new?source=topic/SI-9008&t=1
remote: 
To bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx.git
* [new branch]          topic/SI-9008 -> topic/SI-9008
```

Based on [git- Creating a branch which will be pushed to a remote later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080952/git-creating-a-branch-which-will-be-pushed-to-a-remote-later)

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your git conifg, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters):

```
[alias]
    setupBranch = "!f() { git checkout -b topic/"$1" origin/topic/"$1"; }; f"
```

this will setup an alias `setupBranch` that executes `git checkout -b` with the parameters you specified.

Edit:
Be aware however, that this only works if branch `origin/topic/<topic-name>` exists, else it will fail with a `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'topic/<topic-name>' at the same time.`

Comment: Thanks. I will try this but if the error holds true then I will need to look again for a different solution.

Comment: @JanekBogucki: I'm not sure what you mean by "if the error holds true", but fundamentally, the problem is that you cannot set `origin/blah` as a remote-tracking branch for `blah` if `origin/blah` does not exist yet. If you intend to *create* an `origin/blah` on the remote, you have to actually *do* that, so that `origin/blah` does in fact now exist. This leaves a problem: without first contacting `origin` and asking it, you don't know if `origin/blah` exists yet (though you can check your own remote-tracking branches to see if you got one the *last* time you talked with `origin`).

Comment: I meant if the solution does not work then I would continue looking for a solution. I have updated the problem to remove references to remote tracking branches. Of course ultimately a remote tracking branch will exist by the time the first `git push` is done but I'm not stipulating when it exists.

Comment: Defining the alias with ```git config --global             alias.topic '!f() { git checkout -b topic/"$1" origin/topic/"$1"; }; f'``` led to the error noted: ```git topic test-topic
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'topic/test-topic' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/topic/test-topic' which can not be resolved as commit?```