# How do I create remote branch for pushing to from my machine?

Tags: git, github

Im using gitHub, upto now have a forked repos containg justa  local and remote master branch but Im trying to use branches for each issue so that my pull requests only contain the commit I have just pushed rather than all outstanding commits on master.

So on my machine, modify and commit went okay

```
git checkout -b issue36
vi fix_xml.py
git commit -a -m "#36:Start and end tags no longer added"
```

but `git push` did nothing said upto date

So I went to GitHub and created a new remote branch called issue36 (which is assume is based on master) and tried again

```
git push
```

And this worked and it pushed the changes to remote branch 36

But is there a way I could have created this remote branch from my local machine instead of having to go into github.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git how to create remote branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. If you spell out the origin and branch name, like `git push origin issue36`, Git will create the remote branch for you if it doesn't exist.

Comment: ok thanks some confusion in the linked question as to whether that command does create remote branch it or not but Ill give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a remote branch using you local git console by executing the following command:

```
$git push origin <branch_name>
```

This will automatically create the branch for you in the github.