# Git pushing to remote branch

Tags: git

I tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch) but got confused rather than getting my problem solved.

Here is the scenario.

I have created a branch like `git checkout -b <branch_name>`. I then worked on some changes and did

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m "comment"`

Now all those changes are in my uncommitted local `<branch_name>` branch. What i want to do is to push these changes upstream but i want to push it to a branch which doesn't exist e.g., `<branch_name>_test`

I don't want to push it to my `<branch_name>`. How can i do so.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Simply push this branch to a different branch name

```
 git push -u origin localBranch:remoteBranch
```

If you don't want to `set-upstream`, just

```
 git push origin localBranch:remoteBranch
```

Comment: Just a note on this, if you don't include the `-u` or `--set-upstream` flag, you'll have to type this entire command every time you push. `git push` won't work on it's own until the upstream is set.

Comment: You know... Flags like `-u` really confuse a beginner. Just type the whole command and understand how it works. I like this symple answer.

Comment: By the way, `git push origin remoteBranch` is push your `local remoteBranch` to `remote remoteBranch`;

Answer (score 89):

First, let's note that `git push` "wants" two more arguments and will make them up automatically if you don't supply them.  The basic command is therefore `git push remote refspec`.

The *`remote`* part is usually trivial as it's almost always just the word `origin`.  The trickier part is the *`refspec`*.  Most commonly, people write a branch name here: `git push origin master`, for instance.  This uses your local branch to push to a branch of the same name<sup>1</sup> on the remote, creating it if necessary.  But it doesn't have to be *just* a branch name.

In particular, a *`refspec`* has two colon-separated parts.  For `git push`, the part on the left identifies *what to push*,<sup>2</sup> and the part on the right identifies *the name to give to the remote*.  The part on the left in this case would be *`branch_name`* and the part on the right would be `branch_name_test`.  For instance:

```
git push origin foo:foo_test
```

As you are doing the push, you can tell your `git push` to set your branch's *upstream name* at the same time, by adding `-u` to the `git push` options.  Setting the upstream name makes your git save the `foo_test` (or whatever) name, so that a future `git push` with no arguments, while you're on the `foo` branch, can try to push to `foo_test` on the remote (git also saves the remote, `origin` in this case, so that you don't have to enter that either).

You need only pass `-u` once: it basically just runs `git branch --set-upstream-to` for you.  (If you pass `-u` again later, it re-runs the upstream-setting, changing it as directed; or you can run `git branch --set-upstream-to` yourself.)

However, if your git is 2.0 or newer, and you have not set any special configuration, you will run into the same kind of thing that had me enter footnote 1 above: `push.default` will be set to `simple`, which will refuse to push because the upstream's name differs from your own local name.  If you set `push.default` to `upstream`, git will stop complaining—but the simplest solution is just to rename your local branch first, so that the local and remote names match.  (What settings to set, and/or whether to rename your branch, are up to you.)

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, git consults your `remote.remote.push` setting to derive the upstream half of the refspec.  If you haven't set anything here, the *default* is to use the same name.

<sup>2</sup>This doesn't have to be a branch name.  For instance, you can supply `HEAD`, or a commit hash, here.  If you use something other than a branch name, you *may* have to spell out the full `refs/heads/branch` on the right, though (it depends on what names are already on the remote).

Answer (score 22):

`git push --set-upstream origin <branch_name>_test`

`--set-upstream` sets the association between your local branch and the remote. You only have to do it the first time. On subsequent pushes you can just do:

`git push`

If you don't have `origin` set yet, use:

`git remote add origin <repository_url>` then retry the above command.

Comment: as i mentioned, I don't want to push it to my branch which is `<branch_name>`. I want to push it to a new branch `<branch_name>_test` which as of now doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. Updated my answer. You can name the remote branch anything you want, just adjust the last parameter in the `push` command.

Answer (score 18):

You can push your local branch to a *new* remote branch like so:

```
git push origin master:test
```

(Assuming `origin` is your remote, `master` is your local branch name and `test` is the name of the new remote branch, you wish to create.)

If at the same time you want to set up your local branch to track the newly created remote branch, you can do so with `-u` (on newer versions of Git) or `--set-upstream`, so:

```
git push -u origin master:test
```

or

```
git push --set-upstream origin master:test
```

...will create a new remote branch, named `test`, in remote repository `origin`, based on your local `master`, *and* setup your local `master` to track it.

Answer (score 14):

With modern Git versions, the command to use would be:

```
git push -u origin <branch_name_test>
```

This will automatically set the branch name to track from remote and push in one go.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this command:**

**Command Structure:**

```
git push -u origin <branch_name>
```

**Example:**
if your banch name is **develop** then, your command should be like that...

```
git push -u origin develop
```