# upload files to a branch in github

Tags: git, github

I know there are hundreds of tutorials out there on this, but I couldn't figure where to start. 
I am using a MAC and am on a remote system which runs Ubuntu 14.04.
What I want to do is upload folders to my organization's github repository. There already exists a repo, and I want to create a branch and upload my files and folders in that branch.

I tried doing

```
git branch branch_name
git checkout branch_name
```

However the branch does not show up on the webpage. I also tried creating a branch from the webpage, but I dont know how to upload files to it. I am also not sure how to actually navigate to the repository to which I want to upload.

Please give me instructions as to how I could go about doing this.

Thank you!

Comment: https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

Comment: Were your two commands followed by adding, committing, and pushing to the remote repo?

Comment: @Gavin, No. I was following this tutorial: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge. But stopped after the above mentioned two steps because I was worried that I might commit it to the master :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a remote Git branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Find your repository. (Pick the folder you think it's in, and run `ls -a`. If you see `.git`, you're probably in the right place.

   - If you do not have the repository initilized yet, do one of the following:

     - If you have all the files copied from the repository, all you need to do is `git init`.
     - If you have nothing, run `git clone <https://something/foo/bar.git> <folder you want the repository to be in>`. If you specify nothing for the folder, it will create it in the current folder.
2. Create a branch: You can use a single command instead of the two commands you have in your question: `git checkout -b <your branch name>`
3. Make some changes in the files.
4. Track your changes: `git add <changed file> [<another changed file> [...]]` Note that a changed file can be a folder.

   - If you deleted a file, use `git rm <file>` so Git knows you deleted it.
5. Commit your changes: `git commit -m "what you did"`
6. If you need to push your changes back to the main branch, use `git checkout master` and `git merge <your branch name>`. This will move all commits on your new branch to the original branch.
7. Push your changes to the online repository: `git push`

   - For your first time pushing any branch, use this instead: `git push --set-upstream <https://something/foo/bar.git> <your branch name>`
   - From now on, you can incorporate changes from the online branch to your local by using `git pull`.
   - If changes are made on master that should be in your branch, checkout your branch and use `git rebase master`.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the details ;) . So before I do this, I initialize my repository by doing git init right?

Comment: @rowana No, you should already have the repository. `git init` is for creating a new repository. You just want to create a new branch in an existing repository.

Comment: I did not actually git clone when i downloaded, instead I just downloaded the entire repository as a folder.

Comment: Oh well then git init.

Answer (score 3):

You need to push your branch to your remote repository. Notice that the `-u` option sets the upstream for your local branch, so that every following push refers to the given remote branch.

```
git push -u origin branch_name
```

If you don't have any configured remote repositories yet, you can do so by copying the URL of your repository and add it as a remote repository.

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:/YOU/REPO.git
```

Comment: Doing `git remote add newBranch git@github.com:/YOU/REPO.git` added all the files to master branch and moved the files from master to newBranch. So what is the correct syntax of the command?

Comment: It's `git remote add newRemoteNameAlias git@github.com:/YOU/REPO.git`. Afterwards, you are able push branches.

Comment: This helped to solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a branch with `git checkout -b <branch>`
2. Do stuff & commit
3. `git push --set-upstream <remote> <my_branch>` e.g. `origin <branch>`

All of that if you have a remote set. If not, set a remote first.

Comment: How do I know if I am creating a branch in the right repository? (Because I just have a folder which I want to push, but no clue as to if I did it right..!)

Comment: folder with `.git` folder == a repository.

Answer (score 1):

1. creating a branch from the webpage
2. `git branch branch_name
   git checkout branch_name`
3. `git push origin branch_name`