# Can't push my commit to github

Tags: github

Having trouble pushing my commit to github.

Was having super weird node.js behavior and found the solution was to revert back a commit and then manually overwrite my project with Github's zip download.

That worked for solving my weird node.js behavior but now I can't get GitHub to take the current commit as it's not the head?

My tries:

```
$ git push origin test-branch
error: src refspec test-branch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/name/project.git'

$ git push --force origin master:master
Everything up-to-date

$ git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/master
To https://github.com/name/project.git
! [rejected]        HEAD -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

Any way to save me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test-branch is not on remote, you need to use -u option :

```
git push -u origin test-branch
```

ref [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: what about : git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/test-branch

Comment: added the response to the question

Comment: why you push to master ? push on your branch(test-branch), then use the Pull Request to merge two branches.

Comment: How do I suggest I merge the branches now?

Comment: Are you using Github ?  go to the project and use  "New Pull request" button. 
base : master, compare : test-branch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135475/discussion-between-kossentini-anis-and-chris-chevalier).