# SAP Web IDE doesn't show remote branchese

Tags: git, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I had trouble pushing to a remote repository.

I followed the steps listed [Using Source Control Guide](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?3d736a5630844975ba8dc8c08ca5c785.html)

I could do a fetch without any errors.

When I do a pull, I get the following message:
`Pull request failed Could not get advertised Ref for branch refs/heads/master`

When I do a commit, I get the following message:
`Commit request failed Commit failed. Ref must be HEAD and is HEAD`

When I try to push, I cannot see any remote branch.

I am sure that my login user name and password to git are correct.

In their March update, they added "Create Remote Branches in Git" function.

https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?98fd3efb757d4e39b25740d2f3c83b61.html

Comment: Do you have a master branch on your remote repository?

Comment: isn't it automatically created when i push?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch

Comment: It does. In case of WebIDE I too had issues when the branch didn't exist on the remote. So I created a branch on the remote & then it worked

Comment: How to create a branch on the remote then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get a pull error if you don't have a master branch on your remote repository. You cannot pull from a branch which does not exist.

WebIDE will not show the remote if the branch does not exist on the remote. So you will not be able to push. You should first create a branch on the remote & then try push/pull.

You can do this locally with a git client(like [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/downloads)) & then push the branch to your remote. Create a project folder & navigate to it in your terminal/command prompt. Add some files maybe a Readme.md & run the commands below.

```
git init   //Initialize the repository
git add -A //Add all files to the staging area
git commit -m "Initial Commit" //Commit all changes
git remote add origin https://github.com/YouUser/SampleApp.git    //Add your remote
git push origin master        //Push the branch 'master' to the remote repository
```

Now add the remote in WebIDE &  it should be shown in the remotes.

Answer (score 1):

In their March update, they added "Create Remote Branches in Git" function.

https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?98fd3efb757d4e39b25740d2f3c83b61.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this config to fix the issue.

```
git config --unset branch.master.remote
git config --unset branch.master.merge
```

If this is not working verify that the master branch was not deleted on the remote server (by mistake)

To verify if you have local branches tracked use this.

```
# display the remote tracking branches of your local branches
gir branch -a -v
```

[image]