# creating a remote branch in GIT

Tags: git, branch

I need to create branches on the remote site to track the features that need to be worked upon. 
For that, I saw this thread:
[How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch?rq=1)

Question: is there a better way to create a remote branch?

TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a remote Git branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: Is there some reason why the accepted answer doesn't meet your needs?  As a developer, this is by far the most frequent way you will create a remote branch.  Some repo providers, such as GitHub, allow you to create a remote branch in the actual remote repo.

Comment: Hi - I was wondering if there was something that was new. The answer was quite old. It seemed to be a lot of work just to create a remote branch ...

Comment: As a developer, you will typically crate remote branches just by pushing your local branch to the repo.  If you have some other situation in mind, then let us know.

Comment: The idea was to create branches that note the names of features that need to be developed. A developer would check out a branch, work on the feature, send it back to Gitlab (where a request for merging would "pop-up"), the Integration Czar would look at the request (which points to the branch). If it was OK, he/she would merge the branch into the master. Does this sound like a decent approach for development? It was the reason for trying to create branches on the remote (gitlab) host.

Comment: This sounds like a completely typical Git workflow, and a good one, but the duplicate link you cited should cover you in this case.

Comment: Thanks! After the Integration Czar has incorporated all of the developer branches, he/she would need to get the code to the Consolidation Repository (where the code would be auto-deployed to a consolidation machine). In this case, how can one use Git or Gitlab to "promote" code from one repository to another? In this case, the Integration Czar would promote the code from developers (held in one repository) to the Consolidation repository. Again, how could this be done?

Comment: No, I won't answer that, because you radically have changed your question now.  Stack Overflow isn't a blog site.  If you have a focused question, then ask it, once, otherwise keep researching until you reach that point.

Comment: Hi - for others who need help/assistance with GIT, see this series here (IMHO, I think its pretty good): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXT1ElMEkW8&index=6&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZF9C0YMKuns9sLDzK6zoiV  I have found it to be VERY good in explaining things in Layman's terms. After scouring the internet for answers, it was good, solid and honest information from here. PS - I am in not affiliated with the guy in any way, shape or form.