# How to push a local branch to one of the branches of github?(the local branch is not cloned intead created)

Tags: git, github

I have two branches in my local machine namely master,firstbranch.I have two branches in my github repository namely master and firstbranch_1.Now i want to push from my localbranch(firstbranch) to remote repository of branch firstbranch_1.How should i do it?Note:I have not cloned anything from github.I have first created it my local machine and pushed it into the repo and then made a branch in github.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 0):

Just push. If the branches are not related, then you will probably have to -force it.

```
git push origin firstbranch:firstbranch_1
```

(Assuming that the remote is called origin)

Answer (score 0):

#### Pushing your local branch to GitHub

```
$ git push --set-upstream firstbranch
```

The `--set-upstream` flag is needed "connect" the local and remote branch, thus `origin/firstbranch` will be shown in your Git log and `git status` will show an

```
Your branch is ahead/behind 'origin/firstbranch' by XY commits
```

message if the local and remote branches differ (so you need to `push`/`pull`).

#### "Cloning" (fetching) branch from GitHub

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout firstbranch_1
Branch 'firstbranch_1' set up to track remote branch 'firstbranch_1' from 'origin'.
```

This will "clone" the branch and creates a local `firstbranch_1`, connected to the remote one.

---

Just realized, that I misunderstood your question. To connect local `firstbranch` and remote `firstbranch_1`, use

```
$ git push origin firstbranch:firstbranch_1
```

But this command would fail if the two branches are differ:

```
To https://github.com/whatever/repo.git
! [rejected]        firstbranch -> firstbranch_1 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/whatever/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

If you want to...

#### Replace remote branch with local

```
$ git push --force-with-lease origin firstbranch:firstbranch_1
```

This will force the push, the remote `firstbranch_1` will be replaced with commits of local `firstbranch`.

#### Replace local branch with remote

```
$ git checkout firstbranch
$ git reset --hard origin/firstbranch_1
```

This will drop the changes of local `firstbranch` and move the tip of it to remote `firstbranch_1`.

#### Rebase local branch on top of remote branch

```
$ git rebase origin/firstbranch_1 firstbranch
```

This will keep the commits of `firstbranch_1` and apply `firstbranch` on it.