# Git: delete local copies of branches that aren't listed by `git branch`

Tags: git, ubuntu

I ran `git fetch origin` and similar commands before, which fetched all of my coworkers' branches. However, I don't need them. I need only `master` and my branches. If I run `git branch`, it lists the branches that I created on my machine. For each of these local branches, there's an equivalent branch upstream. How can I delete the local copies of all the other branches?

A related question is, how can I `git fetch` all of my branches without fetching my coworkers' branches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Delete your remote tracking branches

Individually run `git branch -rd origin/branchIDontWant` for each branch, or if there are many you can blow them all away with `git for-each-ref --format "%(refname)" refs/remotes/origin | xargs -I% git update-ref -d "%"`.

#### Fetch desired branches

You could only fetch (or pull) the branches that you want (`git fetch origin branchIWant`) going forward, or configure `git fetch` 
to only fetch desired branches from the remote.

To configure `git fetch` to only pull branches that you desire, you'll need to update your configs for the remote you're pulling from. This is described in more detail here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec. You will want to remove the default refspec `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` from your `.git/config` for the repository. Then, you'll add a refspec `fetch = +refs/heads/branchIWant:refs/remotes/origin/branchIWant` for each branch you want fetched (`branchIWant`).

*Keep in mind I'm assuming you're only using a single remote called `origin`, repeat above steps for more remotes.*