# Git push local branch to remote branch's branch

Tags: git, push, branch

I have remote repository with 2 branches, **master** and **login**. I want to push local changes to **login** branch but it's not working.

```
$ git push origin/login

fatal: 'origin/login' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It says 'origin/login' does not appear to be a git repository, but I have. What's my problem?

```
$ git log

commit f385d950a1f8c6412d91b26d749282d1a3ead27a (HEAD -> upstream, login, develop)
Author: SoojungChae <naan_ace@naver.com>
Date:   Sat Nov 3 06:49:16 2018 +0900

    Edit login logic

commit 6719685fbc7f895a909e2515753c02794591595e (origin/login)
Author: SoojungChae <naan_ace@naver.com>
Date:   Sat Sep 22 23:43:57 2018 +0900

    Block unnecessary things

...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 1):

`git push` takes *two* additional arguments:

- the name of a *remote*, such as `origin`
- the name of a *branch*, such as `master` or `login`

That is, you want:

```
git push origin login
```

It's important to keep these two concepts separate: a *remote* like `origin` is a short name that you and Git use to keep track of a longer name like `https://github.com/some/repo.git` or `ssh://git@github.com/some/repo.git`, which is completely different from a *branch name*.

What makes this confusing is that besides these concepts and terms—*remote* and *branch*—there is a third concept, described by a another sequence of words, usually written as *remote-tracking branch*.<sup>1</sup>  This third concept involves strings of the form `origin/master` and `origin/login`.  It can become very confusing as to when you should write `origin login` and when you should write `origin/login`.

The trick would be to consult the documentation, and keep close track of whether it says *remote* or *branch*.  Unfortunately, the documentation uses neither of those terms, because those are actually special cases of even-more general form.  So the documentation (now, Git 2.19<sup>2</sup>) says:

> `git push` [`--all` | `--mirror` | `--tags`] [`--follow-tags`] [`--atomic`] [`-n` | `--dry-run`] [`--receive-pack=<git-receive-pack>`]
>                     [`--repo=<repository>`] [`-f` | `--force`] [`-d` | `--delete`] [`--prune`] [`-v` | `--verbose`]
>                     [`-u` | `--set-upstream`] [`-o <string>` | `--push-option=<string>`]
>                     [`--`[`no-`]`signed`|`--signed=`(`true`|`false`|`if-asked`)]
>                     [`--force-with-lease`[`=<refname>`[`:<expect>`]]]
>                     [`--no-verify`] [`<repository>` [`<refspec>...`]]

and the two arguments I am talking about here are called the *repository* and the *refspec*, rather than the *remote* and the *branch*.  How one is supposed to get through all of that, as a beginner, is not at all clear.

(This is a long-winded way of saying that the Git documentation is not so great.)

---

<sup>1</sup>I prefer the term *remote-tracking name* now, because while it has *some* of the aspects of a branch name, it also has some that are different.  Either way, though, this third concept takes the form shown above.

<sup>2</sup>Older versions of `git push` have fewer optional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the wrong syntax to push.  `git push` takes a URL, path, or remote as its first argument, and then branches come after that.  So you'd want to type `git push origin login` if you wanted to push your current `login` branch to the `login` branch on `origin`.