# How do I make the same branch from my origin to upstream?

Tags: git, github

So in my forked repository, there is a master and initialization branch. I'm active in the initialization branch and in the upstream repo, there is only a master branch. How do I make that initialization branch in the upstream repo?

Comment: Just try to push, the git CLI will tell you what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+to+create+remote+branch

Answer (score 0):

Do you control also the repository you forked from? If not you need to make a pull request to the owner of that repository.