# How to create multiple git branch and push code over there & merge it?

Tags: github

Can anyone please let me know how I can create new branch on GitHub, and push code over there.

Finally, I want to merge all the code in the `main` file.

Comment: It's unclear what specifically you're trying to achieve, but there are plenty of git tutorials e.g. on GitHub itself: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/hello-world. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] before posting on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge the code on main from a branch on GitHub, that is called a PR (Pull Request)

You can create one on GitHub from your workstation, using [GitHub gh CLI](https://cli.github.com/) (to be [installed first](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation)).

See [`gh pr create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create)

> When the current branch isn't fully pushed to a Git remote, a prompt will ask where to push the branch and offer an option to fork the base repository.
> Use `--head` to explicitly skip any forking or pushing behavior.

So make sure to work locally on a branch which is *not* `main`.