# How do I configure git so I can just push a branch?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

Here's what I want:

```
git checkout -b mybranch
<make changes>
git commit -m'changes'
git push
```

The branch I just created with the changes I made to exist on the remote origin. Furthermore, when I later pull, it should pull the same branch.

My current settings:

```
[push]
    default = current
[branch]
    autoSetupMerge = always
```

What do I need to do to force git to behave the way I want it to? It *used* to work with my current settings, now it just says "everything up to date", which clearly it is ***not*** because this branch does not exist on the remote.

---

Edit: Apparently `pull.default` isn't a valid setting, fine. So I removed it, but that's not causing the incorrect behavior anyway.

Setting `push.default=upstream` is ***DANGEROUS*** since now `git checkout -b <newbranch>` for some reason sets up where you branched from as the tracking branch. So if you're on `main` and create a new branch, `main` is the tracking branch. And `push.default=upstream` will merge changes to `main`. This is ***terrible*** behavior and bewilderingly *more* wrong than `push.default=current`.

Comment: I used to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1519032/818112 and now that no longer works.

Comment: So fine, there's no `pull.default`, then that just gets ignored. It doesn't break anything. But `push.default=upstream` is DANGEROUS. Instead of pushing my branch to the remote, it merged to the master branch *locally*, which is fucking insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
[push]
    default = current
    autoSetupRemote = true
```

git push will automatically setup the remote branch.